# Viewing Statistics Graphs in CruiseControl 1.6

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Using CruiseControl.net 1.6 i can no longer see the view statistics link on the view project page so cannot see the nice graphs containing details about the previous builds.

This feature worked in v1.5. Is there some setting I have to change? or a minimum number of builds before it shows the statistics graphs link?

-- Lee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add `<projectStatisticsPlugin xslFileName="xsl\StatisticsGraphs.xsl" />` to `dashboard.config`?

The line goes under `dashboard > plugins > projectPlugins`.

Comment: will try that tomorrow. under what element in the xml does it go?

Comment: Under `dashboard > plugins > projectPlugins`

Comment: hmm added it quickly with no joy. probably have to restart service or www service or something.. will try tomorrow